# No data found error when reconciling version in sde

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, oracle-spatial, reconcile

I got an error when reconciling a version in the sde database and it seems sde cannot find the data in one table with a specific STATE_ID (for example STATE_ID = 12345 for table abc).

In the delta table of table abc, all records have a same STATE_ID different from 12345(say 67890). Before the issue occurs, I:

1. reconciled and posted all versions and compressed database
2. unregistered table abc and made some schema changes
3. registered table as versioned.

We use Oracle 11g behind sde. Anyone have an idea how I can resolve this and reconcile the version?